Can I use ST-Link V2 in conjunction with MPLABXIDE to program Microchip dsPIC33FJ and related?
Is it possible to dump core of Microchip MCU using ST-Link? Are there any workarounds to make it possible to program these chips using ST Link V2?

There are really cheap tools for the dsPIC, so I guess you don'z need a workaround. https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/pg164100

The answers in Can I use ST-Link programmer for non-ST chips? mention that a ST-Link can be flashed with different firmware. Looking at the possible options:

Black Magic Debug : The Supported Targets are devices with a Cortex-M, Cortex-A or RISC-V 32-bit core.
OpenOCD. The Microchip openocd github project only mentions support for the PIC microcontroller PIC32MX family, which uses a MIPS32® M4K® core.

Therefore, can't see an option to use a ST-Link with a Microchip dsPIC33FJ device.
